# How to change value coming from server in key value form?

Tags: ipad

I want to change a value for particular key that is coming from web server.
my code is like this

```
    NSMutableArray *forumTopicData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *columnArrayNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_id",@"class_id",@"role_id",   @"first_name",@"last_name",@"photo_image_url",@"email_address",@"webpage",@"home_phone",@"office_phone",@"cell_phone",@"aboutme",@"gender",@"is_online",@"role_title",@"display_name",nil];
[tempDict setObject:tempValue forKey:[columnArrayNames objectAtIndex:i]];                  //storing in array after getting from sqlite table


            [forumTopicData addObject:tempDict];
```

can anyone please tell how can i manipulate the value of key value pair coming from server ?

Comment: You dont want to do it like this. Key names can change at any time during development, and when they do, your code will break and you will find yourself scouring through your application code trying to fix every key name. Instead what you want to do is to create a data model of `NSObject` type. Here you simply map each key to each property, then you use this data model across your entire application, and you even create objects from this data model class and use that in your datasource arrays.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use this NSManagedObjectModel.

Comment: I never said `NSManagedObjectModel`.

Comment: oh sorry data model of NSObject. How to do that can you give some example ?

Comment: I think Pavan means to create a new class inherited from NSObject class in which there will be properties mapping to keys. You can represent each entity by object of this class.

Comment: @Yogi That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do have to change your keys within your app. Key names can change at any time during development from the server side, and when they do, your code will break and you will find yourself scouring through your application code trying to fix every key name.

As Yogi eloquently put it, you want to create a class inherited from `NSObject` class in which there will be properties mapping to keys. You can represent each entity by object of this class.

Here's how.

**Step 1:**
Create your custom data model to make data management more easier and cleaner.
Create two new files called `ForumTopicDataModel.h` and `ForumTopicDataModel.m`. They will be a subclass of the `NSObject` class.

This is what your `.h` file would look like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ForumTopicDataModel : NSObject


/*
@"user_id", @"class_id", @"role_id", @"first_name", @"last_name", @"photo_image_url",
@"email_address", @"webpage", @"home_phone", @"office_phone", @"cell_phone", 
@"aboutme", @"gender", @"is_online", @"role_title", @"display_name"
*/

/*
Notice the naming convention used with a prefix of the class name. This make it easy to see all the properties of this particular class during text autocompletion when you are programming.
*/
@property (assign) NSInteger userId;
@property (assign) NSInteger userRoleId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userFirstName;
//Do the same for the rest of the keys that you have.


-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;
@end
```

and in your `.m` file you will have this:

```
#import "ForumTopicDataModel.h"

@implementation ForumTopicDataModel
@synthesize userId;
@synthesize userRoleId;
@synthesize userFirstName;
//Keep synthesising the rest

/*
This is where you explicitly write down the keys.
*/
-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.userId = [[data objectForKey:@"user_id"] integerValue];
        self.userRoleId = [[data objectForKey:@"role_id"] integerValue];
        self.userRoleId = [data objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        //continue for the rest of your keys
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

We are doing this as this will contain easy to work with containers. Its a good way to manage your custom json objects too.

**Step 2**
    Now in your view controller where you will be populating the database and categorising your data, make sure you import your custom `ForumTopicDataModel.h` file

```
NSMutableDictionary *myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//Have a for loop that iterates through your array
for(NSDictionary *currentItem in serverArray){
    ForumTopicDataModel *newItem = [[ForumTopicDataModel alloc] initWithJSONData:currentItem];

    [myForumsArray addObject:newItem];
}
```

Now whenever you need to access a specific property of a particular forum, you simply access the property name of the property value that you wish to retrieve from the ForumTopicDataModel object. The beauty of this is that it keeps all your code clean, and it makes your code easy to debug.

And thats all bro. Goodluck

**disclaimer, I have not tested this code, this should work right off the bat though :)**